# Synchronizing Amazon EC2 with Rsync

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, cloud, rsync

I have 3 servers in Amazon EC2 with Elastic Load Balance.

- Server 1: Master.
- Server 2: Copy.
- Server 3: Copy.

The "Master" server stores my Ruby On Rails application, I'm deploying it to /var/www folder.

Is possible to synchronizing files from server 1 to 2 and 3 with Rsync? If yes, how should I do? If no, what's the best solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I keep the /var/www of some web-servers synced by putting it under version control with [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) (but any version control system should work really).

Gives you more ability to track diffs and rollback than rsync would, but whether it's suitable probably depends on what your content actually is (large binary files with a rapid turnover would be bad).

If you go down this route, don't forget to configure some rewriting rules so the .hgrc folder (or equivalent) isn't visible.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If I deploy my application with Capistrano for both servers is better than using rsync?

Comment: "Better" by what measure ?  There are about a zillion ways of syncing some files on one machine with ones on another.  It all depends on details completely unspecified in your original question.